# (MATLAB App Designer) Key Press Callback for Edit Field

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I have an app that asks a user a question, has the user enter an answer in an edit field, and then has the user click a button to check the answer. It's very click intensive since you have to click the edit field, type your answer, click the check button, and then repeat since the cursor is removed from the edit field when the button is clicked.

I'm looking for a way to allow a user to hit the enter key while their cursor is WITHIN an edit field and have my check answer callback function triggered. I know about the KeyPressFcn callback, but it doesn't work if the cursor is within an edit field. Another possible solution would be to have the cursor placed back within the edit field automatically. The perfect solution would have both happen, completely removing clicking!

Does anyone know if it's possible to do this without using Java? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a standard edit field, the callback function for the edit field is executed when the user presses enter. So if you want to call a function when the user presses enter, for example a function to check the user input, just put that function in the callback function for the edit field.

```
function my_edit_field_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  fprintf(1,'User entered %s\n',get(hObject,'String'));  % this is for debugging
  inputCheck = my_input_checking_function(get(hObject,'String'));
  fprintf(1,'Input check result is: %s\n',inputCheck);  % debugging
```